# Why does Chromium forget my Google login everytime I close?

Tags: chromium

Everytime I quit Chromium, it logs me out of my Google Account. **ONLY MY GOOGLE ACCOUNT.** But I'm not logged out of other websites after quitting Chromium. The toggle button of "*Clear cookies and site data when you quit Chromium*" is turned off.

Comment: Dos this happen with other browsers?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @golimar Nope. Only with chromium.

Comment: @harrymc Linux. However, does it even matter?

Comment: I would suggest to clear all cookies in Chromium, login, and see if it happens again.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks! It seems like it worked. By the way, it there any way to close the question now? Or, it will close automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem was to clear all cookies in Chromium and
do the login again.

Apparently, the problem was a corrupt cookie.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe this actually worked. Thank you!